# Integrar jquery rowspanizer en tabla creada dinamicamente con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

hola buen día tengo un problema que me ha traído bastante lio y es que estoy creando una tabla dinamicamente con JS dicha función solamente agrega filas a la tabla, me gustaría saber como integrar la librería jquery.rowspanizer demo [Rowspanizer](https://codepen.io/saier00/pen/jOOxPVB) ya que con las instrucciones del repositorio no logro integrarlo y que funcione, basicamente el cometido de la libreria es agrupar mediante rowspan los rows que tengan el mismo contenido, pero no se si solo funcione con tablas estaticas o tambien podria hacerse funcionar en tablas dinamicas como en mi caso.

tengo este html básico donde se agregan filas

```
<table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:13px">ITEM</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:13px">BLUNDE</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:15px">TOTAL PARTS</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:15px">NET WEIGTH (kg)</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:15px">GROSS WEIGTH</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:15px">LENGTH (mm)</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:70px">DESCRIPTION</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:40px">PART #</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:15px">BATCH</th>
                <th scope="col" class="theaderBody" style="width:15px">MODEL</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 35px;"  id="new_item"   onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 70px;"  id="new_blunde" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 70px;"  id="new_Tpart"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 70px;"  id="new_netW"   onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 70px;"  id="new_grossW" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 70px;"  id="new_length" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 270px;" id="new_desc"   onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 250px;" id="new_partN"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 85px;"  id="new_batch"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" style="width: 85px;"  id="new_model"  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></td>
                <td><input type="button" size="4" class="add btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="add_row();" value="+ Agregar"></td>
            </tr>
            <button id="combine">Combine</button>
        </table>
```

y despues tengo esta funcion para agregar la fila

```
function add_row()
    {
         var new_item=document.getElementById("new_item").value;
         var new_blunde=document.getElementById("new_blunde").value;
         var new_Tpart=document.getElementById("new_Tpart").value;
         var new_netW=document.getElementById("new_netW").value;
         var new_grossW=document.getElementById("new_grossW").value;
         var new_length=document.getElementById("new_length").value;
         var new_desc=document.getElementById("new_desc").value;
         var new_partN=document.getElementById("new_partN").value;
         var new_batch=document.getElementById("new_batch").value;
         var new_model=document.getElementById("new_model").value;
         
             if((new_item == "") || (new_blunde == "") || (new_Tpart == "") || (new_netW == "") || (new_grossW == "") || (new_length == "")|| (new_desc == "") || (new_partN == "") || (new_batch == "") || (new_model == "")){
                    swal("Todos los campos deben estar llenos");
             }else{
                 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
                 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
                 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML=
                 "<tr id='row"+table_len+"'>"+
                    "<td id='new_itemtd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 35px;' id='new_item"+table_len+"' name='new_item"+table_len+"' value='"+new_item+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_blundetd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 70px;' id='new_blunde"+table_len+"' name='new_blunde"+table_len+"' value='"+new_blunde+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_Tparttd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 70px;' id='new_Tpart"+table_len+"' name='new_Tpart"+table_len+"' value='"+new_Tpart+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_netWtd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 70px;' id='new_netW"+table_len+"' name='new_netW"+table_len+"' value='"+new_netW+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_grossWtd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 70px;' id='new_grossW"+table_len+"' name='new_grossW"+table_len+"' value='"+new_grossW+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_lengthtd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 70px;' id='new_length"+table_len+"' name='new_length"+table_len+"' value='"+new_length+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_desctd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 270px;' id='new_desc"+table_len+"' name='new_desc"+table_len+"' value='"+new_desc+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_partNtd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 250px;' id='new_partN"+table_len+"' name='new_partN"+table_len+"' value='"+new_partN+"' readonly>"+  
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_batchtd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 85px;' id='new_batch"+table_len+"' name='new_batch"+table_len+"' value='"+new_batch+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td id='new_modeltd"+table_len+"'>"+
                        "<input class='form-control form-control-sm' style='width: 85px;' id='new_model"+table_len+"' name='new_model"+table_len+"' value='"+new_model+"' readonly>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td>"+
                        "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' id='edit_button"+table_len+"'   value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'><em class='fa fa-pencil' title='Editar Fila'></em></a>"+
                        "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-success' id='save_button"+table_len+"'   value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'><em class='fa fa-save' title='Guardar'></em></a>"+
                        "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'  id='delete_button"+table_len+"' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'><em class='fa fa-trash' title='Eliminar'></em></a>"+
                    "</td>"+
                 "</tr>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                 document.getElementById("new_item").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_blunde").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_Tpart").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_netW").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_grossW").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_length").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_desc").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_partN").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_batch").value="";
                 document.getElementById("new_model").value="";
                 
             }
    }
```

espero haber sido claro y desde ya gracias por sus respuetas.